# How can I convert the GPS coordinate to find local geographic longitude, lambda?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

Let's say I have a coordinate of `59.3536 N, 18.0578 E`.
How can I calculate lambda (local geographic longitude) from the given value to calculate solar time?

```
ST = LT - 4 * (15deg - lambda) + ET
```

where `ST` = Solar Time, `ET` = Equation of time in min and `LT` = Local time.

`lambda` = ?

So I need to know how to calculate lambda.

Comment: I am not an expert in that matter, but as far as I understand it (and so does chatGPT), Lambda is the local geographic longitude, which is  the 18.0578 E Longitude

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to calculate lambda. You've already got your lambda: 18.0578. However, just be careful when calculating (15 - 18.0578). Since 18.0578 E is at the east of 15 deg E, you should consider the absolute value of this equation. Otherwise, you would obtain the Solar time for:

(15 - (18.0578 - 15)) = 11.9422 E.

I hope that helps.